# how to click with cordinates in appium java?

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android, appium-java

I want to know how to click with coordinates in Appium Java, I want to click on an element by (x,y) as this element is the send button on the keyboard. and it doesn't have a locator

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

TouchAction touchAction=new TouchAction(driver);

touchAction.tap(xPoint, yPoint).perform();

Answer (score 0):

To click on some coordinates:

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
int xPoint = 100;
int yPoint = 200;
touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(xPoint , yPoint)).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue because TouchAction is Deprecated. Then i found

```
public static void tap(AppiumDriver driver, int x, int y) {
    PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
    Sequence sequence = new Sequence(finger, 1)
            .addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ZERO, PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), x, y))
.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()))
.addAction(new Pause(finger, Duration.ofMillis(150)))            
.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
    driver.perform(Collections.singletonList(sequence));
    System.out.println("Tap with Coordinates");
}
```

Calling the method: tap(driver, 200, 200);

this will tap on the coordinates x=200 & y=200